# Colocar botões de next e prev no plugin cycle

Tags: javascript, css

Gente, estou tentando colocar duas `img`, uma *next* e a outra *prev* sobre a imagem do slide do plugin Cycle, mas mesmo com `position: absloute;` tanto a imagem de *next* como a de *prev* não se sobrepõem as demais do slide. Elas são mostradas como imagens do slide o que não era para acontecer. Elas precisam ficar uma do lado esquerdo e a outro do lado direito, fixas sem desaparecer.

No site do plugin tem um exemplo, mas esse controle de *next* e *prev* ficam fora do slide. Preciso que se sobreponham ao slide.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OMG</title>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hover.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/banner.css">
    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('._banner').cycle({ delay: 4000});
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap clearfix">
        <!-- Topo -->
        <div class="top">
            <!-- Menu -->
            <div class="_menu clearfix">
                <div class="logomarca">
                    ivan silva
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="">home</a></li>
                        <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="">trabalhos</a></li>
                        <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="">missão</a></li>
                        <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="">orçamento</a></li>
                        <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="">contatos</a></li>
                        <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="">sobre</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Fim menu -->
            <!-- Banner -->
            <div class="_banner">
                <img src="img/arrow_left.png" class="arrow_left">
                <img src="img/arrow_right.png" class="arrow_right">
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <img src="img/2.jpg">
            </div>
            <!-- Fim banner -->
        </div>
        <!-- Fim topo -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
._banner{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;

    /*...*/
    background-color: white;
}

._banner > ul > li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
}

._banner > ul > li > img{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
}

.arrow_left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.0em;
    left: 1.0em;
    float: left;
}

.arrow_right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.0em;
    left: 1.0em;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Adicione seu código a pergunta Mike, assim poderemos te ajudar.

Comment: @SamirBraga código postado

Comment: O plugin a que te referes é este- > https://github.com/malsup/cycle ?

Comment: @Sergio é esse sim

Comment: Mike, já tentou usar a propriedade "z-index" nessas imagens?